# Mysql join tables and replace area_id from one table with area_name from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I wish that area_id in table `cities` are right-joined by their area-name  which is name_en from table `areas` (the I-emphasis rows).

**Table 1: Cities**

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╗
║ COUNTRY_ID ║ AREA_ID ║    NAME_EN    ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ US         ║       1 ║ Los Angeles   ║
║ US         ║       1 ║ San Francisco ║
║ US         ║       2 ║ Kansas City   ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Table 2: Areas**

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║  NAME_EN   ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ California ║
║  2 ║ Missouri   ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.area_id, c.name_en 
FROM `cities` AS c RIGHT JOIN `areas` AS a ON c.area_id = a.name_en
```

Comment: what are you really looking for? `c.area_id = a.name_en` is not valid since they are of different type, instead it should be `c.area_id = a.id`

Comment: Thank you. When I do it with c.area_id = a.id I get a listing like: US, 1, Los Angeles all from table `cities` without the 1 being right-joined by the area California from table `areas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `RIGHT JOIN` here but instead `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.Country_ID, 
        a.Name_en CountryName,
        b.Name_en AreasName
FROM    Cities a
        INNER JOIN Areas b
            ON a.area_ID = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13dc2/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ COUNTRY_ID ║  COUNTRYNAME  ║ AREASNAME  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║ US         ║ Los Angeles   ║ California ║
║ US         ║ San Francisco ║ California ║
║ US         ║ Kansas City   ║ Missouri   ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Query should be

```
   SELECT c.country_id, c.area_id, c.name_en 
   FROM cities AS c RIGHT JOIN areas AS a ON c.area_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must follow the rule, you don't equal to two field that are completely different type. So you should not make them equal. They are different type.
On the other hand, Right join is not recommended. you should use left join except it.

`SELECT  a.country_id, 
        a.name_en AS country_nameCountryName,
        b.name_en AS area_name
FROM    areas b
        LEFT JOIN cities a
            ON b.id = a.area_id`